# regex pattern in angularjs to allow all characters from english,spanish,german,french,italian,Swedish, numbers and dashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, regex-greedy

Can someone help me with regex that allows only characters from (english,spanish,german,french,italian,Swedish) languages,numbers and dashes. I want to use this regex pattern in angularjs validation.

Comment: I *think* from the wording of your question, you're trying to include European languages and exclude Middle Eastern languages like Arabic and Chinese. A regex for UTF-8 encoding will allow *all* languages if that's what you want. /^\\d{4},[\\s\\p{L}]+$/u is your best bet for a UTF-8 regex. As for allowing European characters while excluding Middle Easter characters, that's incredibly complex, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky!
To match all Unicode Letters with JavaScript regex you can use:
As a first step you would have to filter the languages you want.

```
[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa-\u00aa\u00b5-\u00b5\u00ba-\u00ba\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ec-\u02ec\u02ee-\u02ee\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037a-\u037d\u037f-\u037f\u0386-\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c-\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03f5\u03f7-\u0481\u048a-\u052f\u0531-\u0556\u0559-\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0620-\u064a\u066e-\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06d5\u06e5-\u06e6\u06ee-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff-\u06ff\u0710-\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u07a5\u07b1-\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u07f4-\u07f5\u07fa-\u07fa\u0800-\u0815\u081a-\u081a\u0824-\u0824\u0828-\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08a0-\u08b4\u0904-\u0939\u093d-\u093d\u0950-\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098c\u098f-\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2-\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd-\u09bd\u09ce-\u09ce\u09dc-\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0-\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f-\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32-\u0a33\u0a35-\u0a36\u0a38-\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e-\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2-\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd-\u0abd\u0ad0-\u0ad0\u0ae0-\u0ae1\u0af9-\u0af9\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f-\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32-\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d-\u0b3d\u0b5c-\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71-\u0b71\u0b83-\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99-\u0b9a\u0b9c-\u0b9c\u0b9e-\u0b9f\u0ba3-\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0bd0-\u0bd0\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c39\u0c3d-\u0c3d\u0c58-\u0c5a\u0c60-\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd-\u0cbd\u0cde-\u0cde\u0ce0-\u0ce1\u0cf1-\u0cf2\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d3a\u0d3d-\u0d3d\u0d4e-\u0d4e\u0d5f-\u0d61\u0d7a-\u0d7f\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd-\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32-\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81-\u0e82\u0e84-\u0e84\u0e87-\u0e88\u0e8a-\u0e8a\u0e8d-\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5-\u0ea5\u0ea7-\u0ea7\u0eaa-\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2-\u0eb3\u0ebd-\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6-\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edf\u0f00-\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6c\u0f88-\u0f8c\u1000-\u102a\u103f-\u103f\u1050-\u1055\u105a-\u105d\u1061-\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106e-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108e-\u108e\u10a0-\u10c5\u10c7-\u10c7\u10cd-\u10cd\u10d0-\u10fa\u10fc-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258-\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0-\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f5\u13f8-\u13fd\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u167f\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u16f1-\u16f8\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7-\u17d7\u17dc-\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u18aa-\u18aa\u18b0-\u18f5\u1900-\u191e\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19ab\u19b0-\u19c9\u1a00-\u1a16\u1a20-\u1a54\u1aa7-\u1aa7\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u1b83-\u1ba0\u1bae-\u1baf\u1bba-\u1be5\u1c00-\u1c23\u1c4d-\u1c4f\u1c5a-\u1c7d\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf1\u1cf5-\u1cf6\u1d00-\u1dbf\u1e00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59-\u1f59\u1f5b-\u1f5b\u1f5d-\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe-\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071-\u2071\u207f-\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u2102-\u2102\u2107-\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115-\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124-\u2124\u2126-\u2126\u2128-\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2139\u213c-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u214e-\u214e\u2183-\u2184\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c60-\u2ce4\u2ceb-\u2cee\u2cf2-\u2cf3\u2d00-\u2d25\u2d27-\u2d27\u2d2d-\u2d2d\u2d30-\u2d67\u2d6f-\u2d6f\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u2e2f-\u2e2f\u3005-\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303b-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312d\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31ba\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fd5\ua000-\ua48c\ua4d0-\ua4fd\ua500-\ua60c\ua610-\ua61f\ua62a-\ua62b\ua640-\ua66e\ua67f-\ua69d\ua6a0-\ua6e5\ua717-\ua71f\ua722-\ua788\ua78b-\ua7ad\ua7b0-\ua7b7\ua7f7-\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\ua882-\ua8b3\ua8f2-\ua8f7\ua8fb-\ua8fb\ua8fd-\ua8fd\ua90a-\ua925\ua930-\ua946\ua960-\ua97c\ua984-\ua9b2\ua9cf-\ua9cf\ua9e0-\ua9e4\ua9e6-\ua9ef\ua9fa-\ua9fe\uaa00-\uaa28\uaa40-\uaa42\uaa44-\uaa4b\uaa60-\uaa76\uaa7a-\uaa7a\uaa7e-\uaaaf\uaab1-\uaab1\uaab5-\uaab6\uaab9-\uaabd\uaac0-\uaac0\uaac2-\uaac2\uaadb-\uaadd\uaae0-\uaaea\uaaf2-\uaaf4\uab01-\uab06\uab09-\uab0e\uab11-\uab16\uab20-\uab26\uab28-\uab2e\uab30-\uab5a\uab5c-\uab65\uab70-\uabe2\uac00-\ud7a3\ud7b0-\ud7c6\ud7cb-\ud7fb\uf900-\ufa6d\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d-\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e-\ufb3e\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc]
```